# Circuit Board Design Help (Novice)

Tags: pcb-design, infrared, microprocessor, proximity-sensor

I would like to see if the project that I am currently working on is something that can be done. Any help I can get would be much appreciated. I hope I am providing enough information.

I am looking for some sort of small IR or ultrasonic motion sensor to capture motion within 15 feet (3 meters) in a 45 degree angle. The moving object (a vehicle or bicycle) will be traveling very fast (20 to 50mph). The sensor will have to capture the motion very rapidly and alert me through a flashing LED light and get ready to capture again. The small motion sensor will be attached to a custom made circuit board that will be powered by a small power source (a battery pack preferably). The custom made circuit board wont be not more than 1.5 inch (2.5cm) in width and 2.5 inches (5cm) long. Like I mentioned, I want the circuit board to have a flashing LED light that works as an indicator for motion detected objects. I am trying to get all of this inside a very small custom made plastic case that I can print with a 3D printing machine.

The sensor that I have in mind is the following:

Ultrasonic Sensor: http://www.parallax.com/product/28015

The final product would look something like this. This will give you a perspective on the limited space and final idea.

http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Ultrasonic-Sensor-9846

My questions are:

Would I be able to power this system with a battery pack? If so what power source would you recommend?

Would you suggest an IR sensor over ultrasonic sensor?

Can the PCB be created given the specifications? (1.5W x 2.5L)

Comment: Put another way, you just need a motion detector that flashes an LED whenever motion is detected in a 3 meter arc?

Comment: if you had an easy analog output PIR sensor, with an OpAmp as a "differentiator" and perhaps a buffer amp after that into a 555 time which is configured for one-shot pulse into your little LED indicator. The derivative opamp's gain should be adjustable with a tiny surface mount trimpot, so you can set the sensitivity/magnitude of motion detected, to finally trigger a LED pulse. Total number of components would be the PIR sensor, a few small surface mount resistors and caps, as small as possible trim-pot, a dual package OPAMP which could be a very small SOT363 or SOT23-6, and 555 (SOT23).+1 LED

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a PIR (passive infrared) sensor.  These are amazingly sensitive to IR emittance changes in the environment.  They don't take much power, so can be battery operated.  The electronics should be able to fit on your board easily.  The real problem space-wise is the power source and whatever optics you put in front of the PIR sensor, even if it's just a slit baffle.